# swapping a given node with the next node

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to swap two nodes. The given node will be swapped with the next node (it's a singly LinkedList. However, the node has two fields).
My code isn't working in the node position as before

```
public void swapNodes(int given_d1, double given_d2) {
    Node pointer = first;
    Node previous=null;

    while (pointer != null&& pointer.next != null) {
        previous=pointer;
        pointer=pointer.next;
        if (pointer.data1 == given_d1 && pointer.data2 == given_d2) {
             Node temp= pointer.next.next;
             previous.next=pointer.next;
             previous=previous.next;
             previous.next=pointer.next;
             pointer.next=temp;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're helping yourself by with your choice of `temp` and `pointer` as a variable names, but let's see if we can figure this out :)

You're starting out with 4 nodes under consideration:

```
previous -> pointer -> ? -> temp
```

I think you are hoping to end up with the following:

```
previous -> ? -> pointer -> temp
```

When you set `previous.next = pointer.next` the first time, I think you've correctly started the swap process.

The problem is in the next couple of lines. What you want to have happen is you make `previous.next.next = pointer` and then `pointer.next = temp`.

So you were close, but here's what I think the body of the if statement needs to be:

```
        if (pointer.data1 == given_d1 && pointer.data2 == given_d2) {
             Node temp = pointer.next.next;
             previous.next = pointer.next;
             previous.next.next = pointer;
             pointer.next = temp;
        }
```

Comment: thank you its working but why only the first node not swaping?

Comment: The first node can never get swapped because of what happens when the execution enters the while loop for the first time. Immediately upon entering the while loop for the first time, pointer is "first" and previous is null. However, the first thing that happens in the while loop is that previous becomes "first" and pointer becomes "second". Since pointer ends up getting swapped with what's after it, "first" can never be swapped.